# Contact summary email link open mailto: instead?

Tags: civimail

Noticing a change after update to 4.6.  Within the contact summary, clicking an email link opens up a CiviCRM popup email dialogue.  Is there an easy way to override this behavior and provide a simple mailto: link instead like it used to be in 4.4?

A setting? if not, an extension?

Answer (score 1):

For many people, this new behavior is an improvement, but there are definitely others who preferred the old approach.

The operative line in the template is [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/fa938177202b0ef376e00b6cbe8be3814ef1cd28/templates/CRM/Contact/Page/Inline/Email.tpl#L57), and the only way you don't see that is if outbound mail is turned off on the site.  (In a perfect world, there would be a site-wide setting for this.)

If you want a customization to handle this, the easiest might be to add a bit of jQuery via a .extra.tpl, extension, or theme:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $('.crm-contact_email a.crm-popup').each(function() {
    var email = $.trim($(this).html());
    var emailLink = $('<a/>', {
      class: 'mailto-link',
      href: 'mailto:' + email,
      title: ts('Send an email outside of CiviCRM'),
      html: '<i class="crm-i fa-envelope"></i>'
    });
    $(this).after(emailLink);
  });
});
```

Comment: one other interesting quirk of this new behavior is right-clicking on the email address does not allow the "copy email address" feature of a browser to be used, perhaps because it's not a mailto: